# The quota size of offline storage in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, storage, indexeddb

I have only been using indexedDB for a few day and I have a question about the limit of indexedDB. I have read a lot of documents on the internet and this is what I got:

- The quota size of storage
- Get the size of storage
- Turn the persistent mode on
  But I can not find any information about how to change the quota size of storage(at least in chrome).

Can we change the quota size of storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Chrome. Quota is determined by a heuristic, sites and users can't alter it.

Your best resource to learn more is probably: https://web.dev/storage-for-the-web/